# Different coverage ratio values in Jacoco check vs jacoco report

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jacoco, test-coverage

I have setup Jacoco in my project to do a) check for the code coverage and b) produce a coverage report. The generated HTML report shows the right coverage values but the warning messages that Jacoco check generates at the end of the build process shows different and wrong values. I wonder what I'm doing wrong here.

For example here is what I can see for a util class in the generated HTML report:

[image: jacoco report]

but for the same class I see this when the build is finished:

[image: jacoco check warning]

Here is my jacoco-report config in my pom.xml file:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco.check</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>${jacoco.check.phase}</phase>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${jacoco.skip}</skip>
                <rules>
                    <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
                        <element>CLASS</element>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>com/xxxxxx/**/config/**/*</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/xxxxxx/**/filter/**/*</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/errors/*</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/security/*</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxOnlineWebApplication.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <limits>
                            <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
                                <counter>LINE</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>0.90</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>prepare-unit-tests</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <propertyName>itCoverageAgent</propertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and my jacoco-check config is as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>agent-for-ut</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <append>true</append>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPaths}</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!-- Integration-tests executed with failsafe-plugin -->
        <execution>
            <id>agent-for-it</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <append>true</append>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>com/xxxxxx/**/config/**/*</exclude>
                <exclude>com/xxxxxx/**/filter/**/*</exclude>
                <exclude>com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/errors/*</exclude>
                <exclude>com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/security/*</exclude>
                <exclude>com/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxOnlineWebApplication.class</exclude>
            </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Are you sure the rules can find the data from Jacoco? I see you have changed the dest file location. The rules have a dataFile parameter which by default is <the build directory>/jacoco.exec (see https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html for more info).

Comment: That was fu*ing it! you are a legend @JamesWilson! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thanks, I have added my comment as an answer for anyone else who comes across this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are changing the location that the results are stored in:

```
<destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
```

You will also need to tell the check plugin where to find the data file using the `<dataFile>` item to your rules configuration.

Please see the [jacoco:check docs](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html) for more information.

Comment: That was it! great spotting. Thank you!